# Reliable periodic URL fetch from iOS app

Tags: ios, download, background

We have been looking for a reliable way to periodically get data from a URL from an iOS app, regardless of the state of execution of the app on the device **(foreground, background, suspended or terminated/force-quit)**.

We have gone through all the questions on this topic that are on this site, and their answers, as well as all the relevant iOS documentation from **Apple** and blog posts we can find on the subject.  **But, we have not yet found a solution that will work.**

Here is what has been considered/implemented:

> 1. Background fetch - This is our current implementation.  It works at the whim of the OS as far as the frequency and timing of the fetch goes, and only when the app is not "terminated" or "force-quit" by the user.  This  has been found to be totally unreliable, as the users themselves don't understand the quirks of iOS, and force-quit the app, yet expecting it to function even after that.  The app deals with financial information, and thus can result in loss of potential financial gains to the users if the fetches are not performed on a schedule.
> 2. Change notifications from the server - this is not an option, as we neither store nor wish to store certain information on a server, for privacy reasons.  Therefore, we cannot use this.
> 3. Silent notifications from the server to trigger fetch - again, this won't work if the app has been force-quit, as the notifications are not delivered to the app in that state.
> 4. PushKit - this is what apps like WhatsApp or Vonage would use to fire the app regardless of its state of execution.  However, this is only available to VoIP apps, and we don't fall into that category.  Can this still be used by non-VoIP apps?  If so, we could settle for this but only as a last resort, as the preferred option is to have it all done from the app without involving a server to generate "empty" push notifications, simply for the purpose of triggering a URL download.

Given the nature of the app and the potential for the user to benefit financially, it seems rather harsh that iOS would not allow a simple operation such as a periodic download of a URL.  **So, hoping that someone knows how to overcome this challenge.**

As an aside, the exact same functionality on Android works like a charm, regardless of the app's state of execution.

Comment: What Android does/permits is not relevant. This is iOS. On iOS, you _cannot_ guarantee that code in your will run spontaneously with known periodicity regardless of the state of the app (e.g. running or backgrounded or terminated). Therefore your only choice is a periodic push notification, because the push comes from your server, where you can do whatever you like.

Comment: After the app does the fetch, how would the user gain financially without interacting with your app again?